# Authorization Policy Handlers: When to check claims vs database lookup? When to use cookies?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, permissions, authorization, claims

I have a Windows Authentication Asp.Net Core MVC Application that has an Identity Management piece as an SQL server database. The database is used to store User Identity and also tie that Identity to Applications, ApplicationRoles, and ApplicationPermissions. (Similar to AspNetIdentity but customized)

I am having trouble trying to decide the proper way to implement my Security policies.  As of now I have a permission requirement class and a permission requirement authorization handler.  At startup I look up all permissions for the entire application and register each permission as a policy. I can then use the Authorize(Policy = "perm") attribute on my controllers and actions. This functions just fine. I was wondering if this is the most efficient way to do this and am looking for ideas on how to cut back calls to the database.

I have tried loading all permissions for a user in via Claims Transformation.  This loads all claims but still has to load all claims for the User context in each http request. The plus side is that it only has to look everything up once and then Claims can be checked everywhere else in code that Authorize is used.

```cs
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {

                foreach (var role in IdentityManagementService.GetAllRoles())
                {
                    options.AddPolicy($"Require{role.RoleName}Role",
                        policy => policy
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement(role.RoleName)));
                }

                foreach (var p in IdentityManagementService.GetAllPermissions())
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(p.PermissionName,
                       policy => policy
                       .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                       .Requirements.Add(new PermissionRequirement(p.PermissionName)));
                }

            });
```

Any help / ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The decision how to do it is based on your use case, what are you trying to achieve? If it's database calls, when the user signs in the Claims are attached to the User context, so if you have access to the HttpContext, you can get `User.Claims.First(x => x.Type = "MyClaim");`

Comment: I guess that I just wanted a real reason to load them as Claims.  The benefit of doing so would be that each request I only make one request to the database and get all of the user's permissions then load them as claims. Everywhere else I would write my authorization to check the User's Claims.  Is there a way to maybe cache these as Cookie and check if the cookie already has those claims stored? maybe reducing calls to the database even further? And if I do so, what are some caveats in security holes. I don't want the user to be able to edit their permissions via cookie editing.

Answer (score 2):

First, *everything* is a claim. Even roles are just claims. The principal itself is a `ClaimsPrincipal`, which really just means it's a collection of claims belonging to a particular authenticated user.

Second, anything that exists as a claim is stored in the auth cookie. That's why claims are persistent: they're read from and restored from the auth cookie when it's passed with each request. If you have data that lives in the database associated with the user, then you must obviously pull that out to attach it as a claim, but that should be a one-time occurrence when the user logs in. Every subsequent request should rely on the claim.

The obvious downside of course is that claims don't refresh, so if you have data that can change during the life of the user's authenticated session, claims may not be a good fit for that kind of data. Alternatively, you can invalidate the security stamp, which will cause the auth cookie to be refreshed the next time it's re-validated (once every 30 minutes, by default). You can also opt to simply log the user out and then have them log back in.

Comment: That is true! everything is a claim... My issue is that the only means I have to attach that additional database data as a claim is in the IClaimsTransformation implementation. This is because I am using Windows Authentication scheme. So that transformation takes place each time I am checking if the user is Authenticated I believe. I am also having trouble understanding how to implement  cookies with Windows Authentication.

Comment: So I have transformed the claims and then I load everything into an asp.net core session cookie.  the cookie is good for 20 minutes by default.  The only issue for me now is that there is no way for me to invalidate that specific session unless the user ends their session themselves.  There is no way to do that in .net core short of tricking the IIS server to recycle the app pool. So a user could log in, and then an admin could disable the access of that user and the user would be able to access the resource until the session has expired. (20 minutes of inactivity)